# Using resources without going over the resourcemeanager?

Tags: c#, embedded-resource

In the past I used resources by using `resources.User` as example. Since a few weeks though (maybe an update in between?) I noticed that even though this creates no compile error I no longer got an Auto complete when  I type `resources.` .

Thus I'm now going over the resourcemanager using:  `ResourcesDB2.ResourceManager.GetString("User")`  as example.

I began to wonder though: Is it adviceable to use the method without resourcemanager or is that now the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

Referencing resources by passing their key as string might break when you rename the key.

E.g. if you rename the resource `User` to `UserLabel`, `resources.User` would result in a compilation error. But `ResourcesDB2.ResourceManager.GetString("User")` would only fail at runtime.

So it is preferable to use a direct reference, i.e. the method without `ResourceManager`.

Regarding the problem with IntelliSense: you do not seem to access the resources using the generated static `ResourcesDB2.Designer.cs` class. Try `ResourcesDB2.User` instead of going through a `resources` variable.

---

There is a use for the `ResourceManager` if the key you want to lookup is dynamic, e.g.

```
int weekDayNumber = 3; // 0 to 6
string weekDayName = ResourcesDB2.ResourceManager.GetString("WeekDay_" + weekDayNumber); // "Tuesday"
```

for keys `"WeekDay_0"` to `"WeekDay_6"` in the resource file. Again, this will break easily if somebody renames these keys. Also, if somebody tries to find the usages of the key to be renamed by doing a string search (e.g. searching for "WeekDay_0"), this usage would not be found.

So it would be more robust to do this:

```
switch (weekDayNumber) {
    case 0: weekDayName = ResourcesDB2.WeekDay_0; break;
    case 1: weekDayName = ResourcesDB2.WeekDay_1; break;
    // ...
}
```